# How to Pass User Input Values from One Technical Profile to Another in Azure AD B2C Custom Policy?

Tags: xml, azure, rest, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

I'm working on a custom policy in Azure AD B2C and I'm trying to pass user input values from one technical profile to another within the orchestration steps. Specifically, I have a self-asserted technical profile for user sign-in where the user enters their email and password. After obtaining these values, I need to pass them to a REST API technical profile to make a request and validate the user against a custom database.

I've tried using ClaimsTransformations within the orchestration steps, but I haven't been successful.

These are the 2 technical profiles.

```
<TechnicalProfile Id="REST-API-SignUp">
          <DisplayName>Validate user's input data and return loyaltyNumber claim</DisplayName>
          <Protocol Name="Proprietary" Handler="Web.TPEngine.Providers.RestfulProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
          <Metadata>
            <Item Key="ServiceUrl">https://146a-112-134-225-150.ngrok-free.app/api/auth/login</Item>
            <Item Key="AuthenticationType">None</Item>
            <Item Key="SendClaimsIn">Body</Item>
          </Metadata>
        </TechnicalProfile>

        <!-- This technical profile uses a validation technical profile to authenticate the user. -->
        <TechnicalProfile Id="SelfAsserted-LocalAccountSignin-Email">
          <DisplayName>Local Account Signin</DisplayName>
          <Protocol Name="Proprietary" Handler="Web.TPEngine.Providers.SelfAssertedAttributeProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
          <Metadata>
            <Item Key="SignUpTarget">SignUpWithLogonEmailExchange</Item>
            <Item Key="setting.operatingMode">Email</Item>
            <Item Key="ContentDefinitionReferenceId">api.localaccountsignin</Item>
            <Item Key="IncludeClaimResolvingInClaimsHandling">true</Item>
          </Metadata>
          <IncludeInSso>false</IncludeInSso>
          <InputClaims>
           <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="signInName" />
           <InputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="password" />
          </InputClaims>
          <OutputClaims>
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="signInName" Required="true" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="password" Required="true" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="objectId" />
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="authenticationSource" />
          </OutputClaims>
          <ValidationTechnicalProfiles>
            <ValidationTechnicalProfile ReferenceId="login-NonInteractive" />
          </ValidationTechnicalProfiles>
          <UseTechnicalProfileForSessionManagement ReferenceId="SM-AAD" />
        </TechnicalProfile>
```

These are the orchestration steps.

```
<OrchestrationStep Order="1" Type="CombinedSignInAndSignUp" ContentDefinitionReferenceId="api.signuporsignin">
  <ClaimsProviderSelections>
    <ClaimsProviderSelection ValidationClaimsExchangeId="LocalAccountSigninEmailExchange" />
  </ClaimsProviderSelections>
  <ClaimsExchanges>
    <ClaimsExchange Id="LocalAccountSigninEmailExchange" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="SelfAsserted-LocalAccountSignin-Email" />
  </ClaimsExchanges>
</OrchestrationStep>

<OrchestrationStep Order="2" Type="ClaimsExchange" ContentDefinitionReferenceId="api.localaccountpasswordreset">
  <ClaimsProviderSelections>
    <ClaimsProviderSelection ValidationClaimsExchangeId="LocalAccountSigninEmailExchange" />
  </ClaimsProviderSelections>
  <ClaimsExchanges>
    <ClaimsExchange Id="RestApiSignUp" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="REST-API-SignUp" />
  </ClaimsExchanges>
</OrchestrationStep>
```

Can anyone provide guidance on the correct approach to achieve this? Is there a specific method or configuration that needs to be followed to pass user input values between technical profiles in Azure AD B2C custom policies?

Answer (score 1):

Just make email and password input claims in the API.

Refer to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/restful-technical-profile#input-claims).

But beware. "password" is only available in the sign-in TP.

So you need to copy it via OutputTransformation to some other value and use that in the API.

Also, step 2 seems wrong:

```
<OrchestrationStep Order="2" Type="ClaimsExchange">
  <ClaimsExchanges>
    <ClaimsExchange Id="RestApiSignUp" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="REST-API-SignUp" />
  </ClaimsExchanges>
</OrchestrationStep>
```

Comment: You need to determine the type of authentication that is used.  Most systems have moved from windows authentication to OAUTH2 because OAUTH2 is supported in Windows, MAC, and Linux.  Both types of authentication (Windows and OAUTH2) are shown in link above.  Password is Windows Authentication and not OAUTH2.